# How about 'play cute' or 'play adorable'?

Tags: synonyms, slang, expressions, expression-choice

I wonder if 'play cute' or 'play adorable' is frequently used to stand for 'act cute/adorable' in spoken language. It seems easier to google out 'act cute/adorable' instead of 'play cute/adorable'.

Comment: I only know 50s movies where the cop says *"Don't play cute with me!"* to the uncooperative gangster being questioned. I can't believe anyone still says that (if indeed they ever did, outside of movie scripts). Presumably OP means something different, but I don't know what it is. We need more context, please.

Comment: We're all human beings, so I expect similar situations happen to all of us. But please can you explain what these expressions mean to *you*?

Comment: I am not sure if the following situation would happen in western cultures or not. But in the East, a girl would try or pretend to act cute or adorable when she is with someone on whom she

Comment: has a crush on, such as showing some exaggerated facial expressions. Or, another situation is that some kindergarten teachers in here, even male ones, would purposely utter with a childlike voice when talking to their students. People therefore would think those teachers don't act as who they are, but 'playing cute' or 'adorable'. These similar situations are what I would like to know if 'play cute/adorable' can be used.

Comment: Okay, well like I say, I don't think *play cute* has been much used for decades, and I doubt *play/act adorable* ever has or will be. Also I don't think there will necessarily be any standard expressions (slang or otherwise) that simultaneously cover both a girl acting coy to enhance her sexual attractiveness, and a kindergarten teacher using a childish voice (btw - toddlers in kindergarten aren't called *students*).

Comment: I think @FumbleFingers is right, you're going to need two different words for those situations. The first is flirtatious, but if you described a kindergarten teacher as such, you'd raise some eyebrows. (Though I feel like this wasn't always the case - any thoughts? Was there a time when an adult could have been described as "flirting" with a baby, e.g.?)

Comment: On second thought, "act playful" would work for either situation.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: Your *flirtatious* tops my *coy* for the first context, but the second (adult adopting childish speech/mannerisms with infant) is more ellusive. I think I'll ask specifically for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These have different shades of meaning.  One who "plays cute" is intentionally giving that impression, while one who "acts cute" may be doing it intentionally but may not.

Comment: Does that mean these expressions are understandable by native English speakers if used by a non-native speakers, even though they may be old-fashioned or mean subtly differently?

Comment: Yes. But on the other hand, it might not have quite the meaning you intend (depending on what, precisely, you intend).

Comment: I think this distinction is spurious.

Answer (score 1):

I was always under the impression that "don't play cute" means "don't pretend to be innocent"/"I know you're being dishonest".

Comment: Actually, it could be related to one of the original meanings of _cute_ which was “clever”, or, more appropriate, “shrewd”.