# Word/expression for how adults address children

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Prompted by [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45491/how-about-play-cute-or-play-adorable), what's a good word/expression for an adult adopting childlike speech/mannerisms when dealing with an infant?

I mean where the adult speaks in an exaggeratedly "sing-song" voice, uses childish words like *bow-wow* for *dog*, *choo-choo* for *train*, etc. A style which would be called [condescending](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/condescending) if used with another adult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual term in linguistics is "motherese", but "child-directed speech" is a bit more politically correct.

Answer (score 12):

I've heard it referred to as [baby-talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_talk).

Answer (score 2):

The first word that comes to my mind is [patronizing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patronizing)

Comment: Well I did say it would be patronising/condescending when directed at another adult, but that's not really a factor with babies/children. Actually, I wanted a generic term for the communication style, so one adult could say the equivalent of *Don't patronise me!* to another, using a word that could neutrally describe how Mummy talks to her little treasure.